# Server side syntax for template in kendo toolbar

Tags: kendo-ui

can anybody tell me how to configure my kendo grid that it uses a
x-kendo-template?
The documentation only shows the set up for using client side technology:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/toolbar-template

I expect something like this:

```
.ToolBar(tb=>tb.Template(..some stuff here...))
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use the x-kendo-template blocks server-side as they are actually "compiled" into a kendo template via kendo.template() in javascript before using them.

But what you can do is include more razor in the Grid's ToolBar template:

```
.ToolBar(t => t.Template(@<text>
    @(Html.Kendo().ToolBar()
        .Name("toolbar")
        .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Type(CommandType.Button).Text("X").Id("X");

            items.Add().Type(CommandType.Button).Text("Y").Id("Y");
        })
    )
</text>))
```

Or

```
.ToolBar(t => t.Template(Html.Partial("_ToolBar").ToHtmlString()))
```

or whatever razor code you want to use.

Comment: Thx so far! ..But I do not really get your point I think: I don't want to use x-kendo-template server side but I want to refer to it in my Kendo Toolbar so it uses it. The x-kendo-template itself is a java script block contained in the cshtml file. I already saw examples like this for listview `@(Html.Kendo().ListView(Model)
          .Name("ownerOfferingPreview")
          .TagName("div")
          .ClientTemplateId("ownerOfferingTemplate")`                          Where _ownerOfferingTemplate_ refers to the js x-kendo-template.

Comment: Template and ClientTemplateId are not the same. If you are looking to separate it out use razor as Stephen suggests. http://www.telerik.com/forums/load-toolbar-template-from-x-kendo-template

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you wanted a server-side solution as that is what the .Template() method is for.  I don't believe you can render *part* of the Grid/ToolBar server-side and another part client-side.  The reason you can use the .ClientTemplateId() on the ListView(and on Grid column definitions) is that *that* template is used when each item/cell is rendered which is done client-side as it is not part of the *structure* of the widget but part of the data.